# SpringBoot Actuator not showing scheduled task

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have created a simple demo app with SpringBoot and included the Actuator.
Tasks that are annotated with @Scheduled show up in the Actuator, but those started programmatically do not. Is there a way to get them to show up also?

I have annotated the @EnableScheduling.

My component looks like this:

```
@Component
public class DemoComponent {
    private final TaskScheduler scheduler;

    public DemoComponent(TaskScheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("Hi"), 1000);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

and the result from Actuator only shows the annotated task:

```
{
  "cron": [],
  "fixedDelay": [],
  "fixedRate": [
    {
      "runnable": {
        "target": "com.example.demo.DemoComponent.work"
      },
      "initialDelay": 0,
      "interval": 1000
    }
  ],
  "custom": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code under https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/9623/commits/94b00a7b0681b050bba03b4c49edf2df2ec65376, I would say that you would need to register your scheduled job with `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` instead of directly registering it with `TaskScheduler`. So something like the following should do it:

```
@Component
public class DemoComponent {
    private final ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduler;

    public DemoComponent(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        scheduler.addFixedRateTask(() -> System.out.println("Hi"), 1000);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
```

}

Comment: Excellent, thanks. 
I ended up using the SchedulingConfigurer to access the default ScheduledTaskRegistrar as described here: https://bowenli86.github.io/2016/05/10/spring/Spring-Set-up-and-Enable-Scheduled-Tasks/